# Filter copy parameters in URL

Tags: php, yii2

I create filter form for my data using data provider and search model and have a problem, when my filter parameters copy in url when I click submit button more than one time.

Model's **ApartmentsSearch** `search` method:

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Apartments::find();
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'rooms' => $this->rooms,
    ]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Controller `actionIndex` method:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new ApartmentsSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->get());

    return $this->render('index', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
    ]);
}
```

View with **ListView** widget:

```
<?= $this->render('_filter', ['searchModel' => $searchModel]); ?>

<?= ListView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'itemView' => '_list',
        'options' => [
            'tag' => 'div',
            'class' => 'apartments-list',
        ],
        'layout' => '{summary}{items}{pager}',
        'summary' => 'Показано квартири: <b>{begin}-{end}</b> з <b>{totalCount}</b>.',
        'summaryOptions' => [
            'tag' => 'div',
            'class' => 'summary',
        ],
        'itemOptions' => [
            'tag' => 'div',
            'class' => 'apartment-item',
        ],
]); ?>
```

And **_filter.php** view with form:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'method' => 'get',
]); ?>

<?= $form->field($searchModel, 'rooms') ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Search', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    <?= Html::resetButton('Reset', ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

So, when I input any number in field and click submit I see url like this:

```
http://localhost/?ApartmentsSearch[rooms]=2
```

When I click second time I see url with copied parameter:

```
http://localhost/?ApartmentsSearch[rooms]=2&ApartmentsSearch[rooms]=2
```

I don't want copy parameters in url, I need to change value of any parameter.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

In active form I forgot add `action` property:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'action' => ['index'],
    'method' => 'get',
]); ?>

<?= $form->field($searchModel, 'rooms') ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Search', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    <?= Html::resetButton('Reset', ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```